# Como guardar configurações do programa, banco de dados ou arquivo de configuração?

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, winforms, app.config

Em meu aplicativo, o usuário administrador, pode fazer algumas configurações, por exemplo:

- Configurar se deseja utilizar modelos determinados de produtos, ou fica em aberto para o usuário final digitar.
- Configurar se deseja utilizar tabela TIPE, ou se o NCM ira ficar aberto para o usuário final digitar.

São configurações que afetarão todo o sistema, e muda a logica do processamento.
Hoje guardo esses `set's`, no `app.config`, mas estive me perguntando, seria a melhor maneira?

Talvez, gravar tais configurações no banco e ao executar a tarefa faço um `SELECT` antes para verificar como esta configurado?

Ou não, o `app.config` é realmente para isso, como o nome já diz? acho!

Vamos imaginar, uma aplicação que roda no servidor, não na maquina local.

Comment: Para este tipo de caso, uso no banco, pois por exemplo, se alterar a máquina por algum motivo.. os dados estarão salvos no banco.. e não no computador, salvo no computador apenas coisas necessárias localmente, como por exemplo as configurações de conexão com o servidor, (IP, porta)...

Comment: Entendo, mas vamos imaginar uma aplicação que roda em um servidor...

Comment: Neste caso, já usei o `app.config`, hoje não uso mais, geralmente crio uma classe de configuração e serializo ela, pois tenho mais controle por exemplo, alguns caso que já passei, serializar [fonte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263202/how-to-serialize-font) e [cor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280362/most-elegant-xml-serialization-of-color-structure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O melhor para você nessa situação específica só você pode dizer.

O `app.config` é usado para configurações gerais do funcionamento da aplicação. Normalmente não deve ser usado para configurar funcionamento específico. Nem sempre é fácil determinar o que é um e o que é outro. Entenda que ele não foi feito para ter alterações frequentes.

Se tem um banco de dados eu acho que a maioria das configurações deveriam estar nele.

Até onde eu entendo essas informações são bem específicas e só são úteis se o banco de dados está disponível. Já fiz diversos sistemas assim e nunca sequer cogitei não colocar no banco de dados.

Não consigo imaginar nesse caso porque colocar isso no arquivo de configuração. Pode até ser que precise fazer algo só no banco de dados e sem elas dentro dele seria complicado realizar. Essas informações são de domínio específico e não da aplicação como um todo. É um erro colocar em `app.config`.

## No geral

O que deve colocar na configuração fora do banco de dados:

- o que diz como acessar o banco de dados direta ou indiretamente, que por razões óbvias não pode estar dentro do próprio (pode ser informações de rede)
- informações que outras aplicações ou o ambiente de execução precisam acessar em algum momento
- outras situações que consiga dar uma boa justificativa para por lá.

No banco de dados você tem essa informação mais "protegida". E tem mais recursos, até mesmo para auditoria e versionamento.

Em alguns casos se não quiser colocar no banco de dados, precisa pensar se não é o caso de usar um arquivo de configuração separado. Acho raro precisar de algo assim.

Obviamente que se usar uma biblioteca que obrigue colocar configuração lá, não tem o que decidir, a não ser pensar em trocar de biblioteca :)

Se a aplicação não tem um banco de dados, claro que essa solução não é ideal.

Há quem use o SQLite como arquivo de configuração. Se for só para isso, a não ser que a configuração seja muito complexa, não acho viável. Mas se o SQLite já está lá por alguma razão, aí pode ser uma boa colocar nele.

Se só tem o banco de dados em outra máquina é possível que queria usar a aplicação mesmo desconectado. Aí é motivo para usar um arquivo de configuração. Ou um banco de dados local como o SQLite, se já o usa para alguma outra coisa.

Por outro lado, se deseja que aquele usuário tenha suas configurações preservadas em todas as máquinas que vá usar, colocar as configurações em um banco de dados centralizado é a única opção, ainda que possa existir uma forma híbrida para atender os casos desconectados.

É mais fácil fazer certo no banco de dados.

A regra básica é usar o banco de dados, e só optar por outra forma se tiver um bom motivo para fazê-lo. Mas só deve estar lá configurações que só são necessárias quando o banco de dados está disponível.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Em meu entendimento, tanto app.config no WinForms e o web.config no WebForms, devem ser usados para configurações para funcionamento do sistema, de forma que o sistema não funcione sem determinada configuração.

No seu caso, acredito que isso é parametrização. Parâmetros diferentes fazem o sistema "pensar" diferente. Nesse caso, eu colocaria tal informação no banco. Dessa forma você pode fazer tela para controlar tal parametrização sem precisar mexer nos arquivos físicos do sistema.

Eu faria dessa forma.

Comment: Sim, concordo em partes.. tendo em vista, que mesmo utilizando o app.config, você pode ter uma "tela" para controlar a parametrização.

Comment: Sim, é possível. Aí vai do que cada um quer fazer.